# What is the proper abbreviation for "version"? (in English and Japanese literature)

Tags: abbreviations

I see both (for example) "ProductName v1.0" and "ProductName ver 1.0" and wanted to know what was the proper use for technical/computer literature.

Bonus thanks if anyone knows the proper usage in Japanese of the same acronym, e.g. if its more proper to write "商品名バージョン1.0" as "商品名Ver1.0" vs. "商品名v1.0" in Japanese language literature.

Thank you.

Comment: `ProductName`.1.0 is the standard. If you want to name versions separately, feel free.

Comment: I am thinking that you mean “abbreviation” not “acronym”. BTW, I bet that Yoichi, one of our moderators, knows the answer to the Japanese bonus question. Perhaps he will notice this question.

Answer (score 3):

Standard in all languages that use latin letters is (since english is the language of IT):

```
Product 1.0
```

Examples:

```
MS-DOS 6.2
Windows 3.1
iOS 7.1.1
Safari 5.1.7
Ubuntu 14.04
```

I have also seen `product v1.0`, I just can't remember any examples so I guess it's less common. But I cant remember to have seen `product ver 1.0` at all. This abbreviation is not very common.

But allowed is everything. There is no norm and no law that tells you how to name different versions of your Product. Here are examples:

```
Ubuntu Saucy Salamander
Ubuntu Utopic Unicorn

Windows 95
Windows NT
Windows Vista

Office XP
Office 2013

OS X Mountain Lion
OS X Mavericks
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it confirms what I was thinking about the ver usage.

Comment: @Guest_in_Shiga: If you think it is a good answer, why don't you vote it up?

Comment: @ Hubert Schölnast: because Voting requires 15 reputation, which I don't have...

Answer (score 1):

We usually call a new version of product in the same brand or product line ‘バーション１. (II, III) – Product name +Version I, (II, III,) in integer in Japanese.
In computer hardware and software models which require frequent revisions or model changes of the product, you may have ‘Version 1.0, 1.2, or 1.3,’  but I don’t think I’ve seen the new version product being indicated with a decimal point (e.g. Version 1.0) in other category products. The word, “version” is often omitted. For instance, Toyota had Mark series in Mark ii, iii, iv, v, vi, vii – x.